# Scilab function can't acces Global Variable

Tags: scilab

We are working on a Scilab project for our math class and we're having trouble using global  variables. We're trying to use a global variable as a counter. The counter needs to be modified in multiple functions but everytime the counter doesn't save the new value and reverts to the initialized one. Why does the counter not get adjusted properly?

Concretely the situation is as follows.

```
counter = 0

function checkForA()
  // Do some stuff
  counter = counter + 1
endfunction

function checkForB()
  // Do some stuff
  counter = counter + 3
endfunction

function printCounter()
  disp(counter)
endfunction
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell you need to specify that variables are global explicitly in scilab;

```
global counter
counter = 0

function checkForA()
    global counter
    // Do some stuff
    counter = counter + 1
endfunction

function checkForB()
    global counter
    // Do some stuff
    counter = counter + 3
endfunction

function printCounter()
    global counter
    disp(counter)
endfunction
```

Comment: This works. I didn't know you had to explicitly declare it as global before using it in the functions. Thanks!